# Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7

Anybody knows what this means?

Tried updating my app to ios 7 and tested it on iPad 2 and encountering these warning and error logs in Console:

```
Sep 24 16:23:56 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[118] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.
Sep 24 16:23:56 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[118] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder (null)
Sep 24 16:23:56 iPad installd[59] <Notice>: 0x2d5000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/THISAPP.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Sep 24 16:23:56 iPad installd[59] <Notice>: 0x2d5000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.<bundle>.<identifier>
Sep 24 16:23:56 iPad installd[59] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Sep 24 16:23:56 iPad installd[59] <Error>: 0x2d5000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012
Sep 24 16:23:57 iPad installd[59] <Notice>: 0x2d5000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.08s; Waiting: 0.05s; Installation: 0.53s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.75s
Sep 24 16:23:57 iPad /usr/libexec/lsd[70] <Error>: Need to synchronize with MobileInstallation
Sep 24 16:23:57 iPad /usr/libexec/lsd[70] <Notice>: LaunchServices: Adding com.<bundle>.<identifier> to registration list
```

No Crash Logs are being recorded.

EDIT:

I have this in my info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.<bundle>.<identifier></string>
```

but it's basically com.site.my, I just edited the real name here.

Comment: It sounds like your app doesn't have a bundle identifier.

Comment: it has i just edited it here, so basically it's something like com.site.my =  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.site.my</string> this is in my info.plist

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, And was unable to install the ipa. It always ended with an error "Could not inspect the application package." and some warnings in device console

```
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone mobile_installation_proxy[356] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options   dictionary when installing an app.
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone mobile_installation_proxy[356] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app with unknown bundleID
.
.
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone installd[44] <Error>: 0x101bcc000 -[MIBundle _validateWithError:]: 28: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone installd[44] <Error>: 0x101bcc000 + [MIInstallable installablesAtURL:packageFormat:userOptions:error:]: Failed  to create bundle for …
```

After spending hours, I got it fixed by adding the "Application requires iPhone environment" in info.plist

```
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether your bundle ID is in your plist

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because one of the pods I was using had a "Resources" directory. Fixing this pod following [this advice](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/39758-cannot-install-to-iphone-after-upgrading-to-ios-7/) resolved the issue.